# I expect these items to align horizontally

Tags: html, css, react-bootstrap

I am working with react-bootstrap, and put 3 items in a div. Nothing fancy, you think. Except the horizontal alignment is completely out of whack.

[image: horizontal-align]

I can probably fix it by changing a lot of css, but I want to understand why this is happening in the first place. I guess I am missing something fundamental.

React

```
<div className="InputRow">
  <Label className="inline">New customer: </Label>
  <Field className="inline" onChange={() => this.onChange()} />
  <Button className="inline">Ok</Button>
</div>
```

Css

```
.inline 
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.InputRow
{
    height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: most probably because _Field_ already has styling on it.

Comment: Could you please do some effort to make a reproducable scenario: copy html output from the browser into a html snippet. (add the external libraries as css): https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a flexbox

```css
.InputRow {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div className="InputRow">
  <Label>New customer: </Label>
  <Field onChange={() => this.onChange()} />
  <Button>Ok</Button>
</div>
```

Comment: Quick and simple, I like it. Choosing this as my favorite answer

Comment: @kcid - doesn't really answer your question though, which was "I want to understand why this is happening"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bootstrap Grid Layout to align item in a row.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#page-layout

Just use `<Row>` and `<Col>` from React-Bootstrap.

Comment: That works, nice to solve it in a react way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just give your `.inline` elements `height:100%;` so they get the full parent's height:

```
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

.InputRow {
  height: 32px;
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

.InputRow {
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div className="InputRow">
  <Label className="inline">New customer: </Label>
  <Field className="inline" onChange={()=> this.onChange()} />
    <Button className="inline">Ok</Button>
</div>
```

Comment: That just make the items bigger, but still does not align them

Comment: @kcid in fact they they are aligned.